# portable python 3.x and pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, portable-executable

I am looking for version (custom/beta?) of portable python that is python 3.x and includes pygame.  I know pygame hasn't been fully converted to 3.x yet, but for what I need it for it works perfectly.

Comment: not sure why this is being down voted.  If it's in the wrong forum or written in the wrong way please let me know.  If the answer is "do it yourself" then cool, but just checking that no-one has already solved this issue

Comment: do you mean that you want to create a standalone executable as [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) does?

Comment: more of a portable dev environment

Comment: What OSes should it support (Windows, OS X, Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Pygame, then take your entire Python folder and put it where you want it to go.

If you mean you want to be able to use `python (filename).py` on the terminal, then you will have to change the `PATH` variable in the terminal, or add the shebang line `#!usr\bin\python` onto your programs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have not fully understood what you're after. Still, let me try to answer:

The release of [Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/download/) now includes VirtualEnv in the standard library, now called [venv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

So in a command line you can type

```
/path/to/python3.3/bin/pyvenv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

To create a folder with links to your python 3.3 installation. That new folder makes it easy to install any [PyPi packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) into, for example:

```
cd /path/to/new/virtual/environment
./bin/pip install adventure
```

to install [Adventure](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/adventure/1.3).

You then probably want to follow [PyGames documentation to install the Py3 branch](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/python3porting)

Then, like user beary605 already answered you can bundle up your whole virtual environment of python by tar'ing, rsync'ing or whatever means of distribution you envision.

There's also an older question covering [Python 3 and Pygame compatibility on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362449/pygame-for-python-3-on-osx-mountain-lion).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is nothing like what you are looking for available, however with a little DIY you might be able to alter a version of Portable Python (it's not updated anymore, but there's a version for Python 3). By saying this I am presuming you want to operate this from a flash drive. Depending on what Windows you are running the steps might be a bit different, but I'm guessing they would be similar to the steps in this thread: [pygame not working with portable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119671/pygame-not-working-with-portable-python)